# How i can render Razor view when ASPX file not found?

Tags: asp.net, razor

i have a project built in MVC 2 [ASPX] and i upgrade them to 3. i make the project's view in Razor cshtml.

because project have a theme system they already have some theme built in ASPX and mine theme in Razor.

suppose action call time.ascx then if file not found how i can render time.cshtml instead of that file they actuall call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will happen automatically.

When you return a view or partial view name, MVC will search all registered `ViewEngine`s for a matching view.

Comment: It's work when Views goes in Views folder but in my application it's goes in Themes/ThemeName/Views/ so that's never work if i pass blah/blah.aspx they never change the .aspx to cshtml